# Check whether timezone is dateutil.tz instance

Tags: python, timezone, pytz, python-dateutil

There are several Python packages that implement the `datetime.tzinfo` interface, including `pytz` and `dateutil`.  If someone hands me a timezone object and wants me to apply it to a datetime, the procedure is different depending on what kind of timezone object it is:

```py
def apply_tz_to_datetime(dt: datetime.datetime, tz: datetime.tzinfo, ambiguous, nonexistent):
    if isinstance(tz, dateutil.tz._common._tzinfo):
        # do dt.replace(tz, fold=...)
    elif isinstance(tz, pytz.tzinfo.BaseTzInfo):
        # do tz.localize(dt, is_dst=...)
    # other cases here
```

(The `dateutil.tz` case is a lot more complicated than I've shown, because there are a lot of cases to consider for non-existent or ambiguous datetimes, but the gist is always to either call `dt.replace(tz, fold=...)` or raise an exception.)

Checking `dateutil.tz._common._tzinfo` seems like a no-no, though, is there a better way?

Comment: what other timezone objects do you expect that require something other than `replace`/fold, besides the ones from pytz?

Comment: @FObersteiner I don't know of any yet besides `dateutil` and `pytz`, but the world's a big place.

Comment: Actually, I take that back - `pendulum` is another important one to support.  It seems to use yet a different "standard", `tz.convert(dt, fold=... or dst_rule=...)`.

Comment: Another possible contender: [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Yeah, `arrow` is out there, but it doesn't seem to have the ability to deal with DST in a flexible way (e.g. choosing the fold or handling non-existence - just other arcane stuff like converting to the "proleptic Gregorian ordinal") so to me it's not worth supporting in my use case.

Comment: Don't forget Python 3.9+ has [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) built-in.

Comment: That's a great point @MattJohnson-Pint, I'll want to support `zoneinfo` too in my actual project.  I don't see any specific docs for it concerning how to handle DST/folds/non-existence, so it looks like I'll have to experiment...

Comment: I'm curious about the use case.  You said `"If someone hands me a timezone object..."`- Are you making a library? Even then, can you just have them hand you a string time zone ID instead?  Then you could manage the implementation dependency yourself.

Comment: Yes, making a library; no, can't always ask for a string, one reason is that they may want "the same timezone as some other datetime" and `tzinfo`->`str` isn't supported much of anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for having to be the guy to say, "You shouldn't be doing that in the first place", but you indeed should not be trying to detect whether a time zone is a `dateutil` zone, you should instead just use it as a `tzinfo` object.

From your comments, it seems like the only reason you want to detect this is because `pytz` has a separate localization / normalization stage, but since `pytz` is the *only* library with this unusual interface, it should suffice to detect `pytz` zones.

As I mentioned in my [comment on the dateutil issue](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/1257#issuecomment-1416252077), my recommendations are to either:

1. Not support `pytz` at all, if that is possible. It is effectively legacy software at this point, and if you have a new library you at least don't have any users who are already expecting to use it with `pytz`.
2. If that is not feasible, something like [`pytz-deprecation-shim`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) might be a useful abstraction here. For a new library, I wouldn't recommend introducing time zones like those provided that also expose a `pytz`-like interface, but the [helper functions](https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html) (which don't require a dependency on `pytz`!) can be profitably used or re-implemented to either detect `pytz` zones or seamlessly upgrade them to their modern equivalents. You could also use this in combination with #1 by detecting if a zone is a `pytz` zone and throwing an error.

In any case, there is no particular reason to enumerate all the different time zone providers, since all except `pytz` use the standard interface.

Comment: The Pythonic way to handle `pytz` would be to try `.localize` first, then do the other thing if it raises an exception.

Comment: I must disagree on the assertion of non-need.  `pytz` is *NOT* the only outlier here, the various providers of `tzinfo` implementations have differences in what methods they provide to accomplish different tasks, including methods outside the proper `tzinfo` interface.  If I don't want to add hard dependencies for all the different libraries people might be using, and only use libraries that are already installed/loaded, then I have to take different actions depending on what kind of object is provided.  `if type(x)==y` is indeed an antipattern, but `if isinstance(x,y)` is not.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the ratio of comments to answers (currently 9/0 = ∞), there is no available answer to the surface-level question (how to determine whether something is a `dateutil.tz`-style timezone object).  I'll open a feature request ticket with the maintainers of the library.

Comment: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/1257 created.

Comment: Request was denied.