# Comparing pytz.timezone instances

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, pytz, zoneinfo

I need to compare `pytz.timezone`s for equality, and the behavior I'm observing is quite unintuitive.
I've read a lot about Python time zones, `pytz`, `zoneinfo`, LMT, etc., both on SO and generally on the web. The behavior I'm concerned about does not seem to be obviously related to the typical concerns people have with `pytz` and solved similarly. The only workaround I've found is comparing the `pytz.timezone.zone` strings, which is clunky.
The two examples below show the `pytz.timezone` comparison behavior. Used: Python==3.9, pytz==2022.2.1, pandas==1.5.3. The behavior of `zoneinfo.ZoneInfo` objects is, in contrast, sane and intuitive.

Example 1, LMT:

```
>>> tz = pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")
>>> tz
<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' LMT-1 day, 18:09:00 STD>
>>> tz.localize(datetime.now()).tzinfo == tz
False
>>> pd.DataFrame({'t': [tz.localize(datetime.now())]}).t.dt.tz == tz
True
>>> pd.DataFrame({'t': [tz.localize(datetime.now())]}).t.dt.tz_convert(tz).dt.tz == tz
True
```

Example 2, CST:

```
>>> tz = pytz.timezone("America/Chicago").localize(datetime.now()).tzinfo
>>> tz
<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CST-1 day, 18:00:00 STD>
>>> tz.localize(datetime.now()).tzinfo == tz
True
>>> pd.DataFrame({'t': [tz.localize(datetime.now())]}).t.dt.tz == tz
False
>>> pd.DataFrame({'t': [tz.localize(datetime.now())]}).t.dt.tz_convert(tz).dt.tz == tz
False
```

I expect no `False` comparisons above, which is exactly what I get if I use `zoneinfo` instead.

Comment: I'd be curious what you have in mind with that comparison. I mean, ad hoc I don't see much worth in comparing *timezone objects*. I'd rather compare date/times that have been localized with timezone objects from different sources, to see if those sources implement the underlying time zone rules correctly.

Comment: When you call `localize` you change the internal state of the `pytz` object and it's no longer equal. The `zoneinfo` objects are implemented differently and don't need internal state.

Comment: @FObersteiner Comparing timezone objects is useful for unit testing any code that deals with time zones, to mention one obvious use case.


@MarkRansom I don't see any mention of internal state and its mutation in the documentation of `pytz.timezone.localize`, which simply states `Convert naive time to local time`.


@СергейКох To quote myself, "I expect no False comparisons above, which is exactly what I get if I use zoneinfo instead." I think that's the reasonable ask. To have timezone comparisons behave consistently in the two examples I gave would be also make sense.

Comment: Maybe Paul Ganssles [blog post on pytz](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) helps to clarify the background. My take-away here would be to use zoneinfo if I can. Related: [pytz deprecation shim](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim). Anyways, what do you want to test here, if the tz is set correctly?

Comment: @FObersteiner I was working on unit tests where I need to verify that the timezone-aware datetimes are written and read back correctly from some persistence layer. I do test the datetimes themselves, but I wanted to also make sure that the time zones also match, because datetimes of different zones are considered equal if they correspond to the same time (`dt.astimezone(tz) == dt` evaluates to `True` despite the LHS/RHS datetimes having different timezones).

Comment: related: [Check whether timezone is dateutil.tz instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75314041/10197418)